# Cannot change dock position in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, dock, ventura

I cannot change the dock position in my Mac. I'm using Ventura 13.0.

Does someone know a fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure position immutability is not set.

Quit System Settings and run the following command to delete the preference:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Dock position-immutable
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you.